# Running H2O in databricks

Tags: data-science-model, pyspark, h2o

I am trying to run H2O in databricks. However, when I do the following:

```
hc = pysparkling.H2OContext.getOrCreate(spark)
```

I get the following error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Same. I tried using the Databricks documentation and I get the same error. https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/mllib/third-party-libraries.html#h2o-sparkling-water

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it going to work.  Take a look at the links below.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-classification-regression.html
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html

Find an algo from something in there and run it.  It should work fine.